# JS Object filter on attribute doesn't work if attribute doesn't exists

Tags: javascript

I'm filtering an object and I want to keep only attributes where there is a match between a key and a value.

My code is this

```
  const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, val]) => {  
    return val.collection.family.includes('MyValue');
  }));
```

The issue is that for some attributes collection is not defined, or family is not defined. This cause a console error.

How can I solve?

Comment: Use optional chaining to prevent the errors.

Comment: `return val.collection?.family?.includes('MyValue')`

Comment: Please include an example of input.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's within a filter, you should be able to use optional chaining safely:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, val]) =>  
    !!val?.collection?.family.includes('MyValue');
));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining